Can Docker in the terminal display Python library versions like Docker Desktop?
I'm using Docker Desktop, which provides a GUI feature to easily view the versions of installed Python libraries within a container. This feature is quite handy for managing dependencies and ensuring consistency across environments.
However, I often work in the terminal and want to achieve the same outcome there. Is there a way to list the versions of Python libraries within a running Docker container using just the terminal?


There is a straight forward command
docker exec <container id> pip list

Example in my terminal
docker exec 4a6258c8f783 pip list

Results what you asked
Package                          Version
-------------------------------- -------------

aiodns                           3.0.0
aiohappyeyeballs                 2.3.4
aiohttp                          3.10.1
aiosignal                        1.3.1
amqp                             5.2.0
annotated-types                  0.7.0
appdirs                          1.4.4
argh                             0.26.2
asgiref                          3.8.1
async-timeout                    4.0.3
attrs                            24.2.0
beautifulsoup4                   4.9.3
billiard                         4.2.0
blinker                          1.4
Brotli                           1.1.0
celery                           5.4.0
certifi                          2024.7.4
cffi                             1.17.0
charset-normalizer               3.3.2
click                            8.1.7
click-didyoumean                 0.3.1
click-plugins                    1.1.1
click-repl                       0.3.0
-------------


Thank you. Is there a way to show also the vulnerabilities of each pip package?

You just asked versions in question?
